# Admob AdView not working showing ads

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, ads, android-cardview

Hi there My app doesn't show admob banner ads when I'm loading data from sqlite database into the app here is my code. Can u please help. I'm using admobs test ad unit id . I have also given permissions in manifest. And I'm using the latest Google ads library.
Main activity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        db= new DatabaseHelper(this);
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
        searchView.setQueryRefinementEnabled(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        data = new ArrayList<DictObjectModel>();
        fetchData();

        // Banner Ads

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {return  false; }
```

Content_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
   android:paddingRight="10dp"
   android:paddingTop="10dp"
   android:background="#ededed"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp">


    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/searchView"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/searchView"
       android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
       xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="@string/banner">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: try to addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID") in request

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"`, you have to set `android:layout_width` is `match_parent`. Else, you can use`ads:adSize="BANNER"`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to see if there are any errors.

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
       ..  print the error code to see if there is one
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {

    }
});
```